# MSBuild doesn't create a Web Deploy Package from command line with VS2017 PublishProfile

Tags: asp.net, deployment, cmd, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I use Visual Studio 2017 and have created some publish profiles. One of these is a *CustomProfile1* Web Deploy Package, it works like charm when pressing Publish and i get:

```
 - BuildTest.deploy.cmd
 - BuildTest.deploy-readme.txt
 - BuildTest.SetParameters.xml
 - BuildTest.SourceManifest.xml
 - BuildTest.zip
```

I have tried numerous experiments with msbuild but does not work to generate the files from command line

```
msbuild Buildtest.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=CustomProfile1.pubxml
```

bin and obj folders are getting filled, but apprently CustomProfile1 is not triggered from command line shot?

```
msbuild -version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.6.1586.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is probably confused as to which configuration you want to build,try adding

> /p:configuration=Debug

you can also put Staging or Release depending on which configuration you want.